# How to view debugging output in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, logging

How can I set Visual Studio to provide a similar level of debugging output to [Aptana Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptana#Aptana_Studio) 3?
I am using Visual Studio 2010, C# 4.0, and [Windows Phone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone_7) 7.1.

I am looking to have it output all of the debug information to the console automatically without me having to tell it to - like Aptana.

Comment: If you mean the `Debug` class, it would show up in the output window.  I'm not familiar with Aptana Studio 3, could you describe how it handles debugging in reference to what you're talking about?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set the debug output in your code with `Console.WriteLine` or `Debug.Writeline`.

If you intend instead of build output, you can change verbosity by `Tools > Options > Project and Solutions > Build and Run` and change values of `"MSBuild project build output verbosity"`

Comment: I was looking for a way to have it do it automatically. Like Aptana: I debug it, and it outputs everything to the debugging console without me having to tell it to.

Comment: Sorry but this is not possible in Visual Studio. You need to specify what to be written on output window with Console.WriteLine or Debug.Writeline

Comment: Darn... I was hoping it could

Comment: Look at here if Autos help at all for you. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/10/07/understanding-the-autos-window-vstiptool0103.aspx

Answer (score 23):

[image]

If you want to see variable values while debugging the application you can use "Quick Watch", "Add Watch" or Autos.

In Visual Studio 2010, the Autos Window displays variables on the current line and one line above and below.

Look at [here](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/feature/Visual-Studio-debug-windows) for more debugging window help.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the Output window showing, go to `View -> Output`. If this doesn't cover what you want then edit your question and mention the exact debugging info you are after - VS pretty much has it all, just not necessarily shown by default.